# Where's PayPal's sandbox OIDC discovery document?

Tags: firebase-authentication, paypal, openid-connect

Throughout the internet, this has been asked from time to time but with no real answers, so I'm trying my luck here:

PayPal's OIDC discovery document is located at `https://www.paypal.com/.well-known/openid-configuration`. [1] However, where's the corresponding one for the sandbox? I assume the sandbox uses different URLs.

The background is, I want to wire PayPal with Google's Identity Platform and at the moment I get error messages that the client_id or redirect_uri was wrong. I suspect it's because I use the live discovery document with sandbox client_ids. Unfortunately I cannot test it with prod client_id since the app cannot be confirmed yet.

[1] (There's one at paypalobjects.com as well but this one's not good since its "issuer" claim doesn't match the domain, so paypal.com is the better one to choose)

Comment: Excluding the scopes section, change `.paypal.com` to `.sandbox.paypal.com` and use the result.

Comment: you mean the URIs that are mentioned in the result? That doesn't work since I rely on the discovery document being functional, I can't put my hands on it code-wise. That's the whole point of the discovery document: I present its URL and the rest functions via auto-discovery.